# SQL Schema news feed

Tags: php, sql, feed

I am creating a newsfeed style app which will create a social network for a company.

When you create a status you have the option to select the audience who the status will be visible to, in this instance it will be different businesses within that company.

For example 'John' from 'Business 1' wants to post a status about their quarterly results but only want's people in his business to see it.

However 'Jane' from 'Business 2' is having a baby and want her post to be seen by the whole company (all businesses).

Initially I was planning to create the 'NewsFeed' table with an audience column which contained an array of each business the post would be visible to. eg: ["Business 1", "Business 5", "Business 7"] and the app would check if the business the user is in is contained in the array, if true then it would show the post.

Im not sure this is the most efficient method to do this and doesn't seem particularly scalable.

I have also considered creating a 'NewsFeed' table for each department and depending on the audience option selected on the status update it would insert it into those tables. However if we end up with a lot of businesses I imagine that could be inefficient also?

What would be the best way to structure the tables in the database in order to most efficiently implement this feature?

thanks

Comment: Basically, never store multiple values in one column. There are some serious drawbacks from that, like the indexing wouldn't be efficient at all. Other than that, you've got two good answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Creating 2 / 3 tables will be a better option than having a single table - 
Table 1 >> NewsFeed with columns *NewsFeedId* and *NewsFeedText*
Table 2>> NewsFeedPublish with columns *NewsFeedId* and *BusinessId*

For space efficient design, It's better to have table Business with *BuisnessId* and *BusinessName* but if you do not want to create this table, you can directly use *BusinessName* instead of *BuisnessId* in Table2.

Comment: You should definitely add a business table as well. Otherwise, you would need to update many rows if a business gets a new name plus using integers (in the feed => business table) would result in faster search.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship you're defining is a 1:M relationship. Each status could be visible to 0 or more business.

I would create a NewsFeed table and a Business table, then a table which sits between these two tables - lets say NewsFeedBusiness.

In the NewsFeedBusiness table, you have the NewsFeedID as a foreign key that references NewsFeed and you have the BusinessID as a foreign key to the Business table. I would also add a unique key on NewsFeedID + BusinessID to prevent a NewsFeed record from being in the same business twice.